# Disable password output in logs

Tags: java, struts2, log4j

I have enabled logging for struts2. using basic log4j configuration, I see that when I submit a login form, the username/password is being printed in logs for the parameters interceptor. is there anyway to disable/encrypt this so that the username/password is not explicitly printed in the logs?? Please let me know if anything else is required??

my Log4j Configuration:

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logfile.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=debug, file, stdout
```

Comment: Find the logger that prints the password and turn it off.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but someone can always turn it on so wanted to know if there was some other way to do it? any thoughts??

Comment: If someone can turn your logs on then they have enough access to your application to get the password another way.

Comment: Why do you use DEBUG level on production? It should only be used during development. You can always request via JIRA to instead using LOG.isDebugEnabled() interceptor should base on devMode.

Answer (score 0):

Find the source of your version of [the `ParameterInterceptor` on `Jarvana`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/struts/xwork/xwork-core/2.2.1/xwork-core-2.2.1-sources.jar!/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ParametersInterceptor.java?format=ok) or similar sites, then recompile it:

- with an *encrypted* logging functionality

or

- *without* the logging functionality (and hope you'll never need to see that logs again :)

then substitute it to the real `ParameterInterceptor`.

But seriously... who cares ?

As said in comments, if they're inside the system, this is your last problem.

---

Edit: as suggested by AleksandrM, for Struts you can find the source directly from the official site: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/

Comment: I use Jarvana for a lot of different libraries :) edited with official source link